# in the second call to Post method getting "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, task

I have below method in my ApiController,

```
public  Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] CardParameters paras)
{
        int amount = Convert.ToInt32(paras.Amount);
        int cashout = Convert.ToInt32(paras.CashOut);

        var promise = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();

        void getResponse(string s)
        {   
            promise.SetResult(Request.CreateResponse(s)); // this line executes in 2 seconds
        }

        AdpResponse ar =  getResponse;
        ta.purchase(amount, cashout, ar);
        return promise.Task;
}
```

**"ta.purchase"** method is in a 3rd party app. That app will call the **"getResponse"** method at the end of process.

Client app receive the result on first call to this method.
But from the second call the client receives error **"[InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.]**

Comment: Can you please share how you're constructing the `ta` object? It would also be helpful to describe how the `purchase` method behaves or what it does if possible.

Comment: @DanielCrha the purchase method is in a dll. when this app makes call to a `purchase` method it returns immediately. somehow after few seconds, the result sends to this app via `getResponse` method (a delegate). I have observed that `getResponse` receives result after execution of `return promise.Task` line.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by wrapping the entire process with a Task.
[This](https://en.it1352.com/article/bcc67e3173c54663b97f140b993f54b5.html) article helped me to understand the concept.

The `setResult(s)` complete the task but it does not de-register the task from ASP.net. hence ASP.net throw an error when it try to exit from the method. So I had to use Task. This worked.

```
public  Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] CardParameters paras){
    int amount = Convert.ToInt32(paras.Amount);
    int cashout = Convert.ToInt32(paras.CashOut);

    string myResult ="";

    var _t = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
         
        var promise = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();

        void getResponse(string s)
        {   
            promise.SetResult(s); 
        }

        AdpResponse ar =  getResponse;
        ta.purchase(amount, cashout, ar);
        myResult = promise.Task.Result;
    });
    await _t;
    return Request.CreateResponse(myResult); 
}
```